# Use where clause in dynamic dbset in Entity Framework

Tags: c#, entity-framework, where-clause, dbset

Currently I am using the following code block to create DbSet dynamically and retrieve data from it -

```
Type entityType = Type.GetType("MyProject.Models."+ EntityName + ", SkyTracker");
DbSet mySet = Db.Set(entityType);

foreach (var entity in mySet)
{

}
```

I would like to use a Where clause here i.e. `.Where(m=>m.Id==1)` or something like that.

Is there any way to do it ?

Answer (score 1):

You should use generics here to make it simpler.

```
public DbSet<T> GetDbSet<T>() where T: class
{
    DbContext db = new DbContext("");
    return db.Set<T>();
}

public List<T> GetFilteredData<T>(Expression<Func<T, bool>> criteria) where T : class 
{
    DbContext db = new DbContext("");
    return db.Set<T>().Where(criteria).ToList();
}
```

And you can call these methods as following.

```
Expression<Func<AudioClass, bool>> criteria = ac => ac.Name == "jazz";

var result = GetFilteredData(criteria);
```

Here `AudioClass` is just a sample class I created for example.

This should help you to implement the behavior you want to.